# Errorr installing ODT for vs2019 "Unable to check if Oracle Developer Tools for visual studio installed in this machine. "

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

I'm using two different Visual Studio Version  2019 ans 2017. and I will start a project with oracle databases.
But I couldn't install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (ODTforVS2019_193200.vsix) in my Vs2019. Unfortunatelly I tried a lot of diffrend ways but I didn't succes.

"Unable to check if Oracle Developer Tools for visual studio installed in this machine."

I added picture related with my issue.

[Failed to fix the Configuration message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZwdh.png)

Comment: Do you have any ideas for this issue ? I need help

Comment: avoid pictures and write the eror/warnings instead please

Comment: I couldn't understand clearly. Any problems with my question? I only added the "error message" pic. When I installed this vs extension, it completed but when I wanted to connect to the database server, I got this error. : (